# drawing lines on top of UIImageView which has an image already

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, line, draw, cgcontext

I have a picture black and white of png format that is displayed with an UIImageView. It is a clock shape with no handles. so the background is white - and the circle is black.
Then I would like to draw on top the handles for hours and minutes and I am struggling on how to do that although I am not far I can't make it to work...

When I draw the handles I end up with a big black square (so I can't see through it to see my png behind it) and at least I see my 2 handles (in blue which I wanted). I guess the goal is to make that big black square to be white/transparent and so it should work...

My code is like that below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
......

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);    
[self drawLineForContext:context Width:10.0 angle:hAlpha length:self.frame.size.width/2.0 - 40];
[self drawLineForContext:context Width:5.0 angle:mAlpha length:self.frame.size.width/2.0 - 12];
}
```

What do you think I am missing?

For information, to set the image, I just do it like that, I guess it is correct as it works...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [md objectForKey:Q_DIRECTION_PIC]];
[ivDirectionPic setImage: image];
ivDirectionPic.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
ivDirectionPic.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
geebee

EDIT1: I added the UIColor clearColor but it is still the same... and I do not understand your comment on how to add another subclass with same frame: how please? where?

I am added also the extra function you asked me to post:

```
- (void) drawLineForContext:(const CGContextRef)context Width:(float)_width angle:(double)_angle length:(double)radius
{
CGPoint c = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2.0);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _width);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.center.x, self.center.y);
CGPoint addLines[] =
{
    CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2.0),
    CGPointMake(radius*cos(_angle) +c.x, radius*sin(_angle) +c.y),
};

CGContextAddLines(context, addLines, sizeof(addLines)/sizeof(addLines[0]));
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIImageView` needs to have its `backgroundColor` set to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

If this does not work, simply add add another subclass of `UIView` with the same frame on top of your image view.

Another source of your error might be your `drawLineForContext` methods for which you did not post any code.

Comment: thx Mundi. I added the clearcolor but did not change the black big frame - you'll see it is now in the code. As I wrote above I don't understand your second sentence. How do I add this subclass and where please? I also added the extra code. thanks for your help in advance

Comment: To override "drawRect" you need to "subclass". I mean just add **another** view on top of the image view and do the drawing in there. That would help you isolate the problem.

Comment: which over view should I add? and how on top?

Comment: Which? A `UIView`. How on top? Set the `frame` equal to the image view's frame.

Comment: so in the end I played with it - added the extra view on top but it did not do anything until I realised that I put the class view object in the imageview in IB... then setting the alpha factor to .5. (so I removed the top view in the end) So thanks a lot because for sure you pointed me in the right direction. The only thing I have left but I think it is good enough is that both pictures are quite faded grey... I can't have both very clear in black at the same time. thanks